# Set checked menu

Tags: android, menu

I am creating a menu in android overriding the onCreateOptionsMenu method like so:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Blit").setCheckable(true);
    return true;

}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == 0)
    {
              somevar = !somevar;
              item.setchecked(somevar);

            }
    }
```

The problem is that the menu is never checked ... how can i make my menu checked?

Comment: can u give  some more description of your question?

Comment: @Pinki i want to set programatically a menu checked or unchecked just like a checkbox...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update all menu items when `onPrepareOptionsMenu` is called.

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
        MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
        if (item.getItemId() == 0)
            item.setChecked(somevar);
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a checked menu you should be making your menu of [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/res/menu/checkable.html) type. Then u can have checkable items (none, all , single).